# Returning a generated file and then deleting it off the server

Tags: servicestack

I have a ServiceStack Service, and the service generates a .zip file then returns it via:

`result = new HttpResult(new FileInfo(zipFileName), asAttachment: false);`

followed by (later)

`Directory.Delete(dir); // Containing the zipfile`

`return result`

The problem I have is I now want to delete the generated file, but I can't because it's still busy.
with an invalid access violation.

What's the best way to handle this? Is there a way to write the whole contents to the response stream which would free up the directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to return binary responses which can be seen in the [ImageService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Test/blob/master/src/Test/Test.ServiceInterface/ImageService.cs): e.g. you can:

- return `byte[]`, `Stream`, `IStreamWriter` from your Service which get written directly to the response
- wrap `byte[]`, `Stream` responses in a `HttpResult` to also customize the HTTP Response headers
- write directly to the `base.Response` in your service
- return a custom a custom result

Here's a custom Result example that implements `IStreamWriter` which writes the file to the response stream and deletes the parent directory of the containing file in the `Dispose()` method:

```
public class ZipFileResult : IDisposable, IStreamWriter, IHasOptions
{
    private readonly FileInfo fileInfo;

    public ZipFileResult(FileInfo zipInfo, string contentType="application/zip") 
    {
        fileInfo = zipInfo;
        Options = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { HttpHeaders.ContentType, contentType }
        };
    }

    public void WriteTo(Stream responseStream)
    {
        using (var fs = fileInfo.OpenRead())
        {
            fs.WriteTo(responseStream);
            return;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
       Directory.Delete(fileInfo.DirectoryName);
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> Options { get; set; }
}
```